# Spotify SDK Authentication is not signing in

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I honestly have no idea what is happening here but i was having a problem with my personal app I am building with authentication so I decided to build the default prebuilt test app and when i hit connect, this happens. I was hoping maybe somebody knew what was going on here? https://photos.app.goo.gl/w1HVdABUHws9q8Fs9

Comment: Are there any logs or outputs in the console?

Comment: @KevinGuebert Honestly I don't know. I did the completely dumbest thing and started from scratch but with the web api and it works fine like that